# How do I sync my iPhone photos with an outdated iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

- I have an iPhone 12 Pro Max.
- My iPhone is not currently synced to iCloud. When I try to turn syncing on, I get the message that “Photos synced from Finder will be removed.” Nearly 20,000 photos that will be deleted.
- I logged into my iCloud account and found that I only have a few hundred photos there from several years ago. These photos aren’t on my iPhone. I don’t remember what device these photos synced from. My previous phone was an Android so it may have been one of my MBPs.
- To complicate matters, I have a lot of videos that are largely
  inaccessible on my iPhone. They don’t show up in Photos. They can only be accessed with the TV app. I can’t even see them with Finder. This happened after I
  transferred all of files from my old Android phone to my iPhone using
  a third party app.

Can I somehow delete my existing iCloud Photos, start over, and have it import all the photos and videos from my iPhone? If not, any suggestions on how I can sync my iPhone photos with iCloud without deleting anything?

Anyone know how I can access, move, and backup those video files I mentioned in point 4?